# count number of Chinese character and add in the end of line

Tags: string, bash, text-processing

I have the file, which have a Chinese word in each line like this :

```
王大明 
新型传染病  
電子雷射
```

I want to add the number of Chinese character in each end of line :

```
王大明 3 
新型传染病 5  
電子雷射 4
```

How can I do this?
I know command, `sed, wc`. However, I cannot achieve this work.  I tried many things, but clearly I need help here.

```
sed -i s/$/{length $0}/ myfile
sed -i s/$/{wc -m}/ myfile
awk '{$2=system(awk 'length') OFS $2} 1'  myfile
```

Comment: @Dennis, Please do add your tried commands as your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged for questioners to add in their questions.

Comment: Are the trailing spaces part of the file?

Comment: `awk '{print $0,length}' file` works fine here without the trailing spaces.

Comment: @oguzismail Can you indicate which OS and Awk version you are using, and your pertinent `locale` settings?

Comment: @tripleee Android 10, GNU Awk 5.1.0, en_US.UTF-8

Comment: On Debian Buster, `awk` out of the box is `mawk` which does not seem to support Unicode (`update-alternatives --display awk` to see what it resolves to).  But even with `gawk` and `LC_ALL=en-US.UTF-8` I can't repro. That's still an older version, though (GNU Awk 4.2.1).

Comment: @Cyrus , no . Trailing spaces are not part of the file
@oguzismail  thanks. This work fine in my computer. I will study more about ```awk```. 
@RavinderSingh13 some command I try below, e.g. : ```sed -i s/$/{length $0}/ myfile``` , ```sed -i s/$/{wc -m}/ myfile```, ```awk '{$2=system(awk 'length') OFS $2} 1'  myfile```

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, Ubuntu 20.04, GNU awk 5.0.1, en_US.UTF-8; works fine. Solaris 11.4, Solaris awk, en_US.UTF-8; works also fine, which is really surprising because this awk doesn't even support user-defined functions.

Comment: I figured it out, the locale was not actually defined in the bare Docker image I was playing around in.  With that, I get 3 with GNU Awk 4.2.1 on Debian Buster, too.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly will work will depend entirely on what exactly your input looks like. If you are dealing with Unicode glyphs, use a Unicode-aware tool such as e.g. Python.

```sh
bash$ cat uniline
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.rstrip('\n')
  print(line, len(line))

bash$ chmod +x uniline
bash$ uniline <<\:
> 王大明
> 新型传染病
> 電子雷射
> :
王大明 3
新型传染病 5
電子雷射 4
```

(I had to trim some whitespace from the ends of the lines in the example you posted.)

For the record, my system encoding is UTF-8, meaning the first line's representation as bytes is

```sh
bash$ echo '王大明' | xxd
00000000: e78e 8be5 a4a7 e698 8e0a                 ..........
```

Perhaps see also [Problematic questions about decoding errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors) for some relevant background.

If you are lucky, even Awk and `wc` *might* be locale-aware on your platform. Your `sed` attempts really have no chance of working (though if you have GNU `sed` you could try with the `/e` option; but really, probably don't).  If you have GNU Awk and the `en_US.UTF-8` locale defined, this works, too:

```sh
bash$ echo $'\xe7\x8e\x8b\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe6\x98\x8e' |
> LC_ALL=en-US.UTF-8 awk '{ print $0, length }'
王大明 3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're VERY certain the only multi-byte characters there are chinese, then do

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 '{ print $0, \
                             \
    gsub(/\342|\343|\344|\345|\346|\347|\350|\351|\357|\360/, "&") }'
```

This list of leading-bytes shall correctly account for either 3- or 4-byte code-points related to chinese chars, of either simplified and traditional, plus all special compatibility variants.

Run that in either byte-mode or unicode-mode and it'll give you the same result. Your locale settings **DOES NOT** matter here (as long as your input is already UTF8 compliant text)

If you're definitely in byte-mode or LC_ALL=C, then

```
awk '{ print $0, gsub(/[\342-\351\357\360]/,"&") }'
```

One of the less-mentioned-but-excellent use case for `gsub()` is to use it for purposes of counting occurrences without having to do `split()` or `substr()`.

if you're REALLY pedantic about exactness, the hideous regex i use myself is

```
function isChinese(str6) { return (str6 ~ 

    /\344|\345|\346|\347|\350|\351|
     (\343|\360|\357)(\244|\245|\246|\247|
    \250|\251|\252|\253)|(\357\271|
    \343(\204|\207))(\200|\201|\202|\203|\204|
      \205|\206|\207|\210|
    \211|\212|\213|\214|\215|\216|\217)|(\343\206|
    \357\270)(\260|\261|\262|\263|\264|\265|\266|\267|
    \270|\271|\272|\273|\274|\275|\276|\277)|
     (\343|\360)(\240|\241|\242|\243|\254|\255|\256|\257|\260|
    \261)|\342(\272|\273|\274|\275|\276|\277(\200|
    \210|\211|\212|\213|\214|\215|\216|\217))|
    (\342\277|\343(\204|\206|\207))(\220|\221|\222|
    \223|\224|\225|\226|\227|\230|\231|\232|\233|
    \234|\235|\236|\237)|\343(\200|\210|\211|\212|
    \213|\214|\215|\216|\217|\220|\221|\222|\223|
    \224|\225|\226|\227|\230|\231|\232|\233|\234|
    \235|\236|\237|\262|\263|\264|\265|\266|(\204|
    \206|\207)(\240|\241|\242|\243|\244|
    \245|\246|\247|\250|\251|\252|\253|\254|\255|\256|\257))/) };
```